# google app engine java - redirecting based on domain

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

I have 2 domains for my site which is hosted in google app engine. I want to 301 redirect any request on the less desirable domain to the more desirable domain.

I have tried adding the following to my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.wmar.api.WebServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>redirectFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.wmar.api.WebFilterRedirect</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>redirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For the servlet it hits it, but then I don't know how to just load the static resource (ideally just passing onto some default static file handler) if the domain is correct.

For the filter it doesn't hit it.

What is the best way to achieve what I want with servlet 2.5 / google app engine java?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realize now that the current ideal solution is to create a separate app engine project and point non-canonical domains at it which has a simple servlet that just 301 redirects to the canonical domain.

For Http to https 301s app.yaml can be used with secure: always.

As noted by konqi there are undesirable side effects by trying to do it all in the one app engine project/module.

Comment: The redirect project is tiny and has a trivial warm up time. I don't understand your other comment. Thanks I didn't know about transport-guarantee  in web.xml. I will test this.

Comment: Um my start up times are ~2.7 seconds IF it is not already running (I could also switch to golang if I decide this is too slow in the future). Then since these are 301 redirects the browser will cache them (unlike from javascript) and it is instantaneous in the future. Most domain providers do not provide free 301 redirects which requires a webserver to receive the request. My question was ".. google app engine. I want to 301 redirect any request on the less desirable domain to the more desirable domain." Your solution didn't solve this without huge downsides sorry!